# React Typescript - TS loses autocomplete after removing UNUSED <T> generic variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have this generic component with this interface:

```
interface TextInputProps<U> {
  label: string;
  propertyName: Extract<keyof U, string>;
  value: Extract<U[keyof U], string>;
  onConfirm: <T>(
    propertyName: keyof U,
    value: string | null,
    label?: string
  ) => void;
}
```

And the autocomplete works like a charm, just the way I want it to

[image]

I normally wouldn't add the  because it's in fact, unnecessary,

However if I remove the `<T>` from the `onConfirm` type then I lose the autocomplete:

[image]

any ideas why that happens? Here is a short codeSandbox illustrating the same issue https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-bshd18?file=/src/App.tsx

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* it happens this way, but I can show you how to investigate this, and also what to change so autocomplete works.

First of all, we'll use "hints on hover" to see what's the difference between type of `propertyName` with or without that extra `<U>` in `TextInputProps`

| With `<U>` | Without `<U>` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: with U] | [image: without U] |

Your `TestComponent` is defined using a generic parameter `T`. However, in React code you do not pass any value of this parameter (using <> brackets). This means, that Typescript has to infer (in simple terms, make the "best guess") about  *what the value of `T` is, for a given usage of `TestComponent`*

Now, that "inferred" type will then be used to validate all calls and types, and it will be also used to provide some auto-complete.

As you can see, in the first case (where we have this seemingly obsolete `<U>`), Typescript infers `T` to be a similar type to what you want -- with keys `name, id, testProperty`. That's why editor is able to provide autocomplete. In we remove `<U>`, however, Typescript says "Hmm, I don't know what the value of `T` is, so I'm just going to say it's an empty interface". Hence, no autocomplete.

Now, how to change this code so it works, and there is no redundant `<U>` -- we just have to give Typescript more hints towards what the value of `T` is. One of the ways to do it is the following:

```js
// file: App.tsx
import "./styles.css";

interface TextInputProps<T> {
  propertyName: Extract<keyof T, string>;
  onConfirm: (propertyName: keyof T) => void;
}

interface TestObject {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  testProperty: "test";
}

const TestComponent = <T extends object>({
  propertyName,
  onConfirm
}: TextInputProps<T>) => {
  return <div>hello</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const handleConfirm = (propertyName: keyof TestObject) => {}; // this line changed
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestComponent
       onConfirm={handleConfirm}
       propertyName=/> // we now have autocomplete here 
    </div>
  );
}
```

The reason this change works is more or less this: by changing `const handleConfirm` from being generic to pointing *exactly* towards your `TestObject`, we give TS more knowledge regarding what do we want this `T` to be in `TextInputProps`. Hence, it's able to correctly infer the type (check it for yourself), and give you autocomplete

Comment: woah that's a very detailed explanation. Thanks a lot! The more you know...